# How to hide field on editform.aspx using conditional statements?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a column name "Order" and if order is equal to "Car" then show the "Warranty" field, else hide it. I am using script editor for this and here is my code and someone it is not working. Can you point me to a right direction.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

if ($("select[title='Order']").val() != "Car")
{
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').hide();
});

}

else 
{
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').hide();
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the data type of warranty and Order fields?

Comment: Warranty is check box(Yes or No) but Order is multiple choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your jQuery selectors or right, you can try using below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("select[title='Order']").val() == "Car")
    {           
      $("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').show();  
    } 
    else 
    {           
      $("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').hide();  
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. It just hides it. if the condition were true then it never shows.

Comment: Try adding breakpoint from browser's console at `IF` condition and see if you are getting correct select element or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Order" field is a lookup field and allow multiple select, we can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("select[title='Order selected values'] option").each(function(){
        if($(this).text()=="Car"){
            $("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

If the "Order" field is a dropdown list, we can use the code below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').hide();
    if($("select[title='Order']").val()=="Car"){
        $("nobr:contains('Warranty')").closest('tr').show();
    }
});
</script>
```